# C# 6.0 List that is getting syntax Error , ' , '

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I am parsing a webpage, the issue I am coming across is that ["www.abc.com/"]  and  ["www.def.com/"] = new List() is getting a "syntax error,',' expected." I made a class that set property for the HtmlTarget, `public string Id { get; set; } public Action<HtmlElement> Action { get; set; }`, anybody have any suggestions  ?

```
public void Spider(string sURL, HtmlDocument doc, int choice)
{
    var urlTargets = new Dictionary<string, List<HtmlTarget>>
    {
        ["www.abc.com/"] = new List<HtmlTarget>()
        {
            new HtmlTarget
            {
                Id = "search",
                Action = e => e.SetAttribute("value", m_sMfgPartNbr)
            },        
            new HtmlTarget
            {
                Id = "submit",
                Action = e => e.InvokeMember("Click")
            }
        },
        ["www.def.com/"] = new List<HtmlTarget>()        
        {        
            new HtmlTarget        
            {        
                Id = "part",        
                Action = e => e.SetAttribute("value", m_sMfgPartNbr)        
            },        
            new HtmlTarget        
            {        
                Id = "submit",        
                Action = e => e.InvokeMember("Click")        
            }        
        }        
    };

    List<HtmlTargets> targets = null;

    if (urlTargets.TryGetValue(url, out targets))        
    {        
        var inputs = doc.Body.GetElementsByTagName("input");

        foreach (HtmlElement element in inputs)        
        {        
            var id = element.GetAttribute("id");

            foreach(var target in targets)        
            {        
                if (target.Id == id)        
                    target.Action(element);        
            }        
        }        
    }        
}
```

Comment: this is not valid syntax for initalizing a dictionary - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx. ie google 'c# initialize dictionary'

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I believe that syntax is only valid beginning with C# 6.0 so if the OP isn't using 6.0, then it won't work.

Comment: That is entirely correct, this is new C# 6.0 syntax.

Comment: @CompressedAir Are you using VS 2015 and targeting the 4.6 Framework? If not, you'll have to use the older syntax.

Comment: i'm using VS 2015, and yes D Stanley, answered my question. I am fooling around with C# 6.0 right now.

Comment: When I try creating a console application with your code it won't even compile. I get an error on each assignment to `Action` that says, "`Delegate 'Action' does not take 1 arguments`" If I change the `Action` property to `string` and then change all the assignments to a string value it compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: He doesn't have to be targetting the 4.6 framework, that syntax is available for older .NET runtimes as well, as long as he's using the new compiler to compile it.

Comment: He also posted generics in the text without using the quote syntax for code, which masked the fact that he had an `Action<HtmlElement>` in there, and not just `Action`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax prior to C# 6 would be

```
var urlTargets = new Dictionary<string, List<HtmlTarget>>
 {
    { "www.eciaauthorized.com/search", new List<HtmlTarget>()
           ... 
     },
     { "www.findchips.com/search", new List<HtmlTarget>()
           ...
     } 
}
```

Comment: The syntax in the question should also be OK, provided the OP is using C# 6.0.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks, clarified.